# Why doesn't my browser refresh when the Nuxt.js dev server recompiles my code?

Tags: docker, containers, nuxt.js, web-frontend, hot-module-replacement

I am working in a CentOS 7 VM (VirtualBox, host is Windows 10) and my working directory is a shared folder.

I have created a node container to develop a Nuxt.js app with the following command:

`docker run --name nuxt-fun -v "${PWD}:/$(basename $PWD)" -w "/$(basename $PWD)" -p 3002:3000 --entrypoint sh -it node:16-alpine`

I successfully installed Nuxt using `yarn create nuxt-app nuxt-fundamentals`.

I added the following to the `nuxt.config.js` file to enable hot module replacement HMR and access from `http://localhost:3002/`:

```
server: {
  host: '0',
  port: 3000
},
watchers: {
  webpack: {
    poll: true
  }
}
```

When I then run the dev server with `yarn dev` I see the following

```
$ nuxt

   ╭────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                        │
   │   Nuxt @ v2.15.8                       │
   │                                        │
   │   ▸ Environment: development           │
   │   ▸ Rendering:   server-side           │
   │   ▸ Target:      server                │
   │                                        │
   │   Listening: http://172.17.0.2:3000/   │
   │                                        │
   ╰────────────────────────────────────────╯

ℹ Preparing project for development                                                                                                                                  13:58:35
ℹ Initial build may take a while                                                                                                                                     13:58:35
ℹ Discovered Components: .nuxt/components/readme.md                                                                                                                  13:58:35
✔ Builder initialized                                                                                                                                                13:58:35
✔ Nuxt files generated                                                                                                                                               13:58:35

✔ Client
  Compiled successfully in 7.53s

✔ Server
  Compiled successfully in 5.02s
```

I go to `components/Tutorial.vue` and modify the content of a p tag and save the file.  The code is recompiled by the dev server but in order to see it in my browser I must manually refresh the page.

Is there some config that I'm missing?

**Update1:**
After 30s I see this error in the console:
`EventSource failed loading: GET "http://localhost:3002/__webpack_hmr/client".`

Comment: I'm not sure about the `webpack.poll`, never saw that one. It should be running HMR out of the box without any other configuration. Could you try to remove that configuration please? Also, what happens if you edit the Tutorial file? Do you see a `↻ Updated components/Tutorial.vue ` in your CLI?

Comment: If I remove the webpack.poll then the dev server won't recompile when the source file is saved.  This setting seems to be needed when running inside a container.  I've needed to use it's equivalent before when using 'stand alone' Vue. My code recompiles OK, the issue is that I have to refresh the browser. I've never had to do that before with HMR.